# XSMTP API Filters others events than opentrack and clicktracking

Tags: sendgrid

Reading the XSMTP API documentation i can see that is possible suppress the open event  and click events using webhooks  in a per message basis. We have a requirement to disable all hooks for some messages. Is that possible? If yes how i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement this yourself. One easy way would be to add a `noEvents` category to the messages that you don't want to track. Then in your webhook callback, if the event contains the category `noEvents`, skip it.

Comment: This will drive my bosses crazy. They think it's a "end of world" waste if send grid keep calling our web hook in cases where we already now that is not important to know anything after they are dispatched. I will suggest to create an other account with webhooks disabled or settle with just filter the messages as you suggest. Thanks